# Why my yahoo finance url not working for querytables.add connection from web

Tags: excel, vba, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to create a worksheet that can retrieve historical stock data from yahoo finance. The code works six or seven months ago without 365 subscription. And I found it's not working now. Here is my code:

```
Sub Button4_Click()
 
    Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim Symbol As String
    Dim qurl As String
    
    Dim SD As String
    Dim ED As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Set DataSheet = ActiveSheet
        StartDate = DataSheet.Range("B1").Value
        EndDate = DataSheet.Range("B2").Value
        Symbol = DataSheet.Range("B3").Value
        Range("C7").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
       
        SD = DateDiff("s", "1/1/1970", StartDate)
        ED = DateDiff("s", "1/1/1970", EndDate)
       
  
        qurl = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/" & Symbol & "?period1=" & SD & "&period2=" & ED & "&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true"
           With DataSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl, Destination:=DataSheet.Range("C7"))
               .BackgroundQuery = True
               .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
               .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
               .SaveData = True
           End With
           
           Range("C7").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("C7"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
               TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
               Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=False
           Range(Range("C7"), Range("C7").End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "mmm d/yy"
           Range(Range("D7"), Range("G7").End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "0.00"
           Range(Range("H7"), Range("H7").End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "0.00"
           Range(Range("I7"), Range("I7").End(xlDown)).NumberFormat = "0,000"
           
           'Worksheets("Grab data").Range("C7:xlDown").Select
           Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

The error keeps showing as:

Unable to open the url. And the internet cannot return the object you requested.

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Yahoo Shut down there free finance service .

Comment: Indeed, the URL now returns a `HTTP 401`

Answer (score 0):

Found out that this code works on mac(without a 365 subscription) but not wondows. Windows with a 365 subscription can just use the web query to get it quick.